# Subclass NSCoder - failable initializer or not?

Tags: swift, init, nscoder

I am using Xcode 7.2 beta. 
I am trying to make a class model to conform to NSCoding.

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
```

Xcode wants me to provide implementation for this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

I saw that I can remove the "?", and nobody complains. I also found this in swift programming language doc:

"You typically define a failable initializer that creates an optional instance of the appropriate type by placing a question mark after the init keyword (init?). Alternatively, you can define a failable initializer that creates an implicitly unwrapped optional instance of the appropriate type. Do this by placing an exclamation mark after the init keyword (init!) instead of a question mark.

You can delegate from init? to init! and vice versa, and you can override init? with init! and vice versa. You can also delegate from init to init!, although doing so will trigger an assertion if the init! initializer causes initialization to fail."

My code works with or without "?" - I believe because of this failable initializer, being so versatile. Could someone explain me more?

I've provided this for my initializer:

```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
    name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Name) as! String
    id = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.ID) as! Int
    imagePath = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.ProfilePath) as! String
    movies = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Movies) as! [Movie]
}
```

Should it be any difference if implementing init without failable?

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

I've did the encodeWithCoder impl, so no need of nil checks in the initializer:

```
 func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(title, forKey: Keys.Title)
    aCoder.encodeObject(id, forKey: TheMovieDB.Keys.ID)
    aCoder.encodeObject(posterPath, forKey: Keys.PosterPath)
    aCoder.encodeObject(releaseDate, forKey: Keys.ReleaseDate)
}
```

Which one would you recommend for working with NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Answer (score 0):

Can your class / object handle any of those items in the `init` function to be `nil`?  You didn't declare them as optional, so I'm assuming the answer is no.

A failable initializer is what you would use in case any of those items does end up being unloadable / unarchiveable.  In that case you'd return `nil`, a failure case.

More information about failable initializers can be found [in this Apple Swift blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17), which I was just looking at.

Comment: Ok. This is helpful. Could you explain why I can use here also the failable or the non-failable one? Because either seems possible. Thank you

Comment: Either one seems to be possible for you, but if it were my code I'd probably prefer the failable initializer approach because I'd want to inform anything trying to instantiate my object of a potential failure case, versus trying to continue with some object that might not have been fully properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty interesting, I wasn't aware that you could implement a failable initializer as non-failable and still be able to compile with Xcode complaining of non-protocol conformance.

Which initializer you use entirely depends on the intent you want to express. Consider the case of the developer that comes along after you're long gone. If they see `init?` they'll immediately know that the initializer either succeeds or it returns nil whereas `init` is making a promise that it **always** succeeds. In this case, it's best to conform to the protocol exactly as specified since it's safe to assume Apple had a good reason for making the initializer failable.

Comment: Thank you. But why do you think is it possible to have it both ways? (I've already read that you didn't know till now) Do you have a guess?

Comment: I would always go with whichever option the docs suggest. Which in this case is the failable initializer because it keeps things consistent.